# What is the difference between 전까지 and 까지?

Tags: grammar, difference

So what are the different use cases for ~까지 and ~전까지, both meaning 'until'? When can one be used but not the other?

Example: "내 문제가 되기 전까진 본 적도 없어요"

I had not seen it until it was my problem.

Couldn't they have just said "내 문제가 되기 전에 본 적도 없어요" and had the same meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'전' translates as *before* or *ago*

> 내가 집에 오기 전에 = Before I came home

> 5 년 전에 - 5 years ago

'까지' translates as *to or until/ a place or time*

> 100까지 센다 = count to 100

When 전 is placed before 까지 as in 전까지 it means before this specific time.

> 5 시 전까지 만나자 = Let's meet before 5 o'clock

전까진 is not interchangeable with 전에 and has a different nuance.
전까진 means 'all' the time before or leading up because it is connected with 까지 which means 'as far as' or 'till'.

While 전 just means 'before' or 'ago.' So the nuance of the two sentences are different in how they convey 'before'

> 내 문제가 되기 전까진 본 적도 없어요

Has the nuance of 'In all the time before and up until' or even 'In all my life' before it became my problem, I never experienced it. While

> 내 문제가 되기 전에 본 적도 없어요

Has the nuance of 'The time before' it became my problem I never experienced it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I'll give my example: "내 문제가 되기 전까진 본 적도 없어요" I had not seen it until it was my problem. Couldn't they have just said "내 문제가 되기 전에 본 적도 없어요" and had the same meaning?

Comment: I edited this into the question so I can expound on my answer.